# Custom angular directive isn't showing up?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know this question has been asked many times before, but I've read through tons and none of them seem to be relative to my issue.

My console is error-free and my browser sources show the necessary code has been loaded.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <goal-chart>Loading directive...</goal-chart>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  /**
   * @desc create d3 charts for goal progress and completion
   * @example <goal-chart></goal-chart>
   */

  angular
    .module('goalTracker')
    .directive('goalChart', goalChart);

    function goalChart() {
      return {
          template: '<h1>GOAL CHART</h1>'
      };
    }
})();
```

and I have a primary route config file:

[image]

All that shows up is:

[image]

This custom directive is part of a much larger application that is being bundled, hence why I haven't posted a plnkr.

Comment: any console error?

Comment: There are no console errors.

Comment: have you missed to run angular on page like by either `ng-app="goalTracker"` or bootstrap app module

Comment: Everything else on the page is working correctly, so the ng-app is clearly working. And restrict: 'E' didn't change anything

Comment: Yes that will not make any effect, by default restrict is `AE` type

Comment: Have you tried moving the definition of goalChart() above the directive definition?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax on your module declaration is wrong.  Should be:

```
  angular.module('goalTracker', [])
```

Working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/lCiMyHwGCKd7OwfquFWC).

Comment: There is a master config file that already lists dependencies in the module, so it is not necessary to also add the second argument on the directive's module declaration. And the lack of the second argument in the module is pretty much the only obvious/useful angular error, but I'm not getting that.

Comment: @PankajParkar - the code as show in the question does throw errors to the console

Comment: @jbrown, I have added to the main question to clarify.

Comment: @jbrown I know, but that doesn't mean OP haven't declared a module, if he isn't then it should have throw an error..

Comment: @PankajParkar - I was just going off what he was showing.  Hard to make assumptions about what he wasn't showing.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

I was relying too heavily on my Gulp tasks to track changes and update the all.js file correctly. The HTML was added to the project, but the directive's js was not being bundled. Thank you for everyone's prompt assistance.